# Can BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT give a custom compilation error string?

Tags: c++, boost

Is it possilbe to get BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT to give a custom compilation error message? I belive the following is an attempt to do that in the code base I'm working in.

```
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT( (MAX_NUMBER_OF_USERS == 15) && ("MAX_NUMBER_OF_USERS is no longer set to 15") );
```

Personally I'm not sure the error message gives anything - I'd rather have it placed as a comment next to the assert.

Comment: Also static_assert(condition, "message") from C++0x should already be rather widely supported.

Answer (score 2):

For static assertion, I would recommend:

[`BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/assert-msg.html)

You pass a C++ identifier like 'message' and it will appear in the error stream.

Comment: I would add that the other BOOST_MPL_ASSERT macro is better than static assert since the error message has a lot of *'s in it.